# I'm done. I miss you

Tags: bug, review

Or is it *I miss you "I'm done"...*?

Sometimes a new question pops up in the active (or newest) questions list, I flag it because it's off topic and get on with my life.

Sometimes, that question pops up again in the low quality review queue. I'm offered choices: *Loos OK*, *Edit*, *Recommended Close*, *Skip*.

Off course, I though it should be closed the first time I flagged it so I hit "Recommend Close".

I get this dialog:

[image]

*Sorry for the wide screenshot.*

I can't chose anything from that dialog because I have already made my choice (*"Wake up Neo"*). Now I'm left with *Loos OK*, *Edit* and *Skip*, none of which feels right.

If I remember correctly, other review queues have the *I'm done* button available because it detects that you have already done something on the question.

I guess it's a bug and an *I'm done* button should also be available when you have already flagged the post.

Comment: nextime you come across such a review make sure to copy the URL...

Answer (score 2):

Just hit "Looks OK."

The review queue interface tries to focus on only letting you do certain "valid" actions for a given queue type, or something. I think it's pretty annoying, but it is what it is. In the cases where I can't do the thing I want to do, I usually open the question in a new tab and hit "Looks OK" on the queue (interpreting it as "looks okay, none of the four actions you want to let me do right now apply).

Then I do what I wanted to do in the first place in the new tab.